# Question : char d = -1 printf("%u",d); why outpt is not 255

Tags: c

I confused about first "printf" function print d is not 255, why d is 4294967295, anyone can help me explain that

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char c = -1;
    char d = -1;
    int i = -1;
    printf("c=%u,d=%u,i=%u\n", c, d, i);
    printf("c=%d,d=%d,i=%d\n", c, d, i);
    return 0;
}
```

output is

[image]

Comment: When you use the wrong printf format operator for the variable type, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Try `%hhu` for better results.

Comment: What you're doing is undefined behavior. It could as well output `cats and dogs`.

Comment: See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.21.6.1 paragraph 9.

Comment: Your plain `char` type is signed; `d` is converted to `int` in the argument list to `printf()` because of the default promotion rules for types smaller than `int`; you printed `-1` (4-byte integer size) as an `unsigned int` and get the result shown.  It's UB, but your result is what you normally get in the circumstances.  If your plain `char` was an unsigned type, you'd get different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely sequence of events in your C implementation is:

- In `unsigned char c = -1;`, `-1` is converted to `unsigned char`, producing 255, and `c` is initialized to this value.
- `char` is signed in the C implementation you are using, so `char d = -1;` initializes `d` to −1.
- `int i = -1;` of course initializes `i` to −1.
- In `printf("c=%u,d=%u,i=%u\n", c, d, i);`, the `unsigned char` and `char` values of `c` and `d` are automatically promoted to `int`, and you pass the values 255, −1, and −1 to `printf`.
- The bits that represent these `int` values 255 (24 zeros and eight ones), −1 (32 ones), and −1 (32 ones) are passed to `printf`, but your `%u` conversion specifiers tell `printf` to expect `unsigned int` values. `printf` responds by interpreting these bits as if they were `unsigned int`.
- In `unsigned int` in your C implementation, 24 zero bits followed by eight one bits represents 255, so `printf` prints that for the first conversion.
- 32 one bits represents 4294967295, so `printf` prints that for the second and third conversion.
- In `printf("c=%d,d=%d,i=%d\n", c, d, i);`, all the arguments after the format string are `int` after automatic promotion, and `%d` tells `printf` to expect `int`, so everything works as expected, and `printf` prints 255, −1, and −1.

Because your argument types in the first `printf` do not match the conversion specifiers, the C standard does not define the resulting behavior. Although the above is likely what happened in your C implementation, the C standard does not guarantee this will happen in other C implementations or even in other programs doing this in this C implementation.